# Dont properly understand how async/await/promises work

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, promise, async-await

I am relatively new to node.js and javascript in general. In particular, I am confused about promises and async/await. I am trying to asynchronously request images from a remote URL and convert them to base64.
Can someone explain what is wrong with my code below?

```
    function loadAsync(image){
        return new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
            request({url: image, encoding: null}, function (err, res, body) {
                if (!err && res.statusCode == 200) {
                    let base64prefix = 'data:' + res.headers['content-type'] + ';base64,'
                    let image = body.toString('base64');
                    let complete = base64prefix + image;
                    resolve(complete)
                } else {
                    return reject(err);
                }
            });     
        });
    }

    async function getImagesAsBase64(images){
        let promises = [];
        images.forEach(image =>{
            promises.push(loadAsync(image).then(results =>{
                return results;
            }));
        });
        const imagesAsBase64 = await Promise.all(promises);
        return imagesAsBase64;
    }

   //Following returns Promise{<pending>} when given an array of images
   console.log(getImagesAsBase64(images));
```

Comment: you can rewrite your second function as `async function getImagesAsBase64 (images) { return Promise.all(images.map(loadAsync)) }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Silly me, I needed to `await` the result by doing

```
let imagesAsBase64 = await getImagesAsBase64(images);
console.log(imagesAsBase64);
```

Comment: BTW you don't need the `then()` callback with `return results`. You could just do `promises.push(loadAsync(image))`